# HttpURLConnection Error - java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection, payload

I am trying to connect to a URL from a desktop app, and I get the error indicated in the Title of my question

Url:https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user

The Code fragment.

```
    public void getUrl(String urlString) throws Exception
            {
            String postData=String.format("{{\"first_name\":\"%s\",\"last_name\":\"%s\",\"email\":\"%s\",\"password\":\"%s\"}}", "FIRST", "LAST","test@test.com","USER_1_PASSWORD");
          URL url = new URL (urlString);
          HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setDoOutput(true);
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",""+postData.length());
          connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic MGZjY2RiYzczNTgxY2EwZjliZjhjMzc5ZTZhOTY4MTM6MzcxOWExMjRiY2ZjMDNjNTM0ZDRmNWMwNWI1YTE5NmI=");
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

          connection.connect();

          byte[] outputBytes =postData.getBytes("UTF-8");

          OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
          os.write(outputBytes);

          os.close();
          InputStream is;
          if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
              is = connection.getErrorStream();
          } else {
              is = connection.getInputStream();
          }
          BufferedReader in   =
                new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (is));
          String line;
          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println (line);
                }
}

public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception
    {

        System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

        Test s = new Test();
        s.getUrl("https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user");
    }
```

When i dig in the response and print error Stream My output is ::

```
{"errors":[{"code":65536,"message":"Invalid payload"}]}
```

any help appreciated

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931164/urlconnection-error-java-io-ioexception-server-returned-http-response-code-4 || check this, it may help?

Comment: i have gone through that url also and used the code from there itself.But i am getting different error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong caused by unecoding. Just have a try by using Base64.encode.