# Facebook PHP SDK 3 issue in access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook PHP SDK. After the user allows my application, facebook redirects to may web page.
Following is the URL

```
http://Mydowmain.com/facebook.htm?state=d96afbb9ea550fg81c287b7822cee0af1&code=AQDtl7Rd7qgCp6S_dXwOCxxfXo1dEh75ZJqrCINMawCUzxOYs9JnpmWKMoYTgjuNhQx2nk8pleCdvGqSt39F2pHKMHt3aNxwqoIah2oshPKKC0MnWycPSU0yLAKMYVQV2g3jRQdEMf2dWTVUrk_ammSpGaYbfFQ3GeccZ1vGqfVazsaQ_1Lxz7GjITlqgCxrOlc#_=_
```

I need to fetch the access_token
Following is the code

```
if($_GET['code'] != '')
        {

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

When i try to use this **$access_token** to get the user details.

```
$user_profile   =   'https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token='.$access_token;
```

It gives the following error

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

}
```

I dnt what i am doing wrong, it was working with SDK 2 but not working with SDK3

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

this Call Returns the following, in which fistpart before "|" is App ID and After "|" is App Secret..

**`187997367916887|9d87d7a2d26485fd926a000b0c3b2f87`**

Comment: What access token are you actually getting from the getAccessToken call? Print it out for debugging, and check it with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
this Call Returns the following, in which fistpart before "|" is App ID and After "|" is App Secret..

187997367916887|9d87d7a2d26485fd926a000b0c3b2f87

Comment: First of all, generate a new app secret for your app right now – because you just posted your’s on the interwebs (<-stupid). And then, of course an API call to `/me` using that access token fails, because the API can’t know who “me” is supposed to be when using an _app_ access token. If the FB SDK is not giving you a user access token after login, then something went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link out, scroll down to the answer with the following in bold: "When using your Facebook Application's token", hope it helps.

[Facebook access_token invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705756/facebook-access-token-invalid)

Comment: Why should that token he’s using be an _app_ access token?

Comment: It is definitely an app access token - these are returned by the SDK from getAccessToken() when there's no user session

Comment: @lgy... so how can i get access_token other than app access_token

Answer (score 0):

Change your graph call's    api   ('/me')   by  ('/[number or name id]')