# querying the graph api with curl

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl

I want to check how to handle the `access_token`. So, I use `curl` to perform the following queries:

```
curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token -d "client_id=<appId>&client_secret=<secret>&grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri="
```

It returns a value for `access_token`.

Then, I'd like to get the list of my friends:

```
curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends -d "access_token=<token>"
```

It returns this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Any hints ?

Comment: The token you are acquiring in the first step is an _app_ access token – but using one of those, the API has no way of knowing who `/me` is supposed to be. Either get a user access token and use that, or request `/userid/friends` with an app access token, and have the user give the app the required permission once before. And you __have to__ use GET for requesting a user’s friends, not POST – you can not exchange those to methods at your own liking, the API has defined which method to use for what action for most endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the debugger? Debug your access token here, it'll tell you abou that access token, and if its tied to a user:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Also, why are you using POST to get /me/friends?

Comment: The debugger returned only my AppId. No other info. And you're right, I could have used GET instead.

Comment: Keep in mind there is no way to auth a USER via curl. You can get an access token, but that was only based on your app_id and app_secret. To get an access token for a user, you need to send them to the login dialog. Once they're redirected back to your app, you have the access_token that is tied to both a user and your app

Comment: Ok. It's more clear. The problem now is to handle the expiration of that token. But it's another story.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way is to use graph API explorer, go there and get and acces token with your facebook developer account:

> Generate a Basic User Access Token
>
> When you get to building your own app, you'll need to learn about
>   access tokens and how to generate them using Facebook Login, but for
>   now, we can get one really quickly through the Graph API Explorer:
>
> ```
> Click on the Get Token button in the top right of the Explorer.
> Choose the option Get User Access Token.
> In the following dialog don't check any boxes, just click the blue Get Access Token button.
> You'll see a Facebook Login Dialog, click **OK" here to proceed.
> ```

You can use the graph api explorer as curl, but if you want to try it with a real curl the sintaxis is as follows for last api v2.8:

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCES_TOKEN' -XGET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me'
```

in my case:

```
toni@MBP-de-Antonio  ~  curl -i -H 'Authorization: Bearer MY-ACCES_TOKEN' -XGET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-app-usage: {"call_count":2,"total_cputime":3,"total_time":3}
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-fb-trace-id: BnLv25AHTjq
facebook-api-version: v2.8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
x-fb-rev: 2929740
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
ETag: "39875e94193dcd62dcbbf583fc0008c110820a6c"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-FB-Debug: fvO9W8Bfl+BihEy/3aZyzOiMrXOkrbK8q1I3Xk2wYnI7sSujZNC6vQzR4RoTWK7K3Hx6EdzoE2kZ/aWhsXe4OA==
Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 06:55:52 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 61

{"name":"Antonio Juan Querol Giner","id":"10204458008519686"}%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be the "/me" identifier you're using when you try to access your own data. (Depending on what your client ID is set as you may be referring to the application instead of yourself, try it with your profiles ID instead of "/me").

Also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/6701982/1546542

Comment: I found this query to get my id from my browser:`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<token>`. But it returned the same error as above: "code": 2500. Do you know another query ?

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the "https://...." , with double quote after curl -X POST.