# Facebook SDK PHP: return friends details

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I have a web service that servers Android, IOS and Windows Phone. Each app connects to Facebook using native SDK and passes the `fb_user_id` and `access_token` when performs API's requests. The API should retrieve the user and friends details and save them on MySQL.

The system works fine, except that it can't return friend's retionship, location and birthday.

```
$fb = new Facebook([
    'appId' => my_app_id,
    'secret' => my_app_secret
]);

$r = $fb->api("$fb_user_id/?fields=friends.fields(relationship,birthday,location)&access_token=$access_token");
var_dump( $r );
```

My app on Facebook has `friends_relationships`, `friends_location` and `friends_birthday` permissions. When we test using a Facebook user setted as developer, the app returns all the information, but when a non-developer uses we can't return those informations.

Any idea?

Comment: fb_user_id/friends?fields=birthday,location,relationship_status works fine. Are you getting any error?

Comment: No error. It just returns the public information. Not sure why.

Comment: If you wrap your code in try-catch and catch OAuthException, it should show you if there is an error.

Comment: I'll try this and post the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what happened!

Facebook's SDK generates a token for `/me`. In PHP I was calling `fb_user_id?fields=friends.fields(id,name,birthday,etc)`. But requests with `/fb_user_id` can't return info with a `/me` generated token.

It works when used directly on browser `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.fields(id,name,birthday,etc)`, but fails when called by Facebook's PHP class:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

My solution:

```
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name&access_token=$this->access_token";
    $this->me = file_get_contents ( $url );                 
    $json = json_decode($this->me, true);
```

For further information, checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705756/facebook-access-token-invalid#answer-6701982). New ideas are welcome.